# SVN sessions issue

Tags: apache, svn, configuration, authentication, settings

I'm new to setting up and using svn server, and I met with a weird problem during using the server.

I used this guide to set up:

http://noobcode.blogspot.com/2010/03/what-is-subversion-as-quoted-by.html

The problem is:

I created a user like in the guide, and also a second one.

I trying to access the repo with the later created user it works, but for the first one, I couldn't login. (But when I renew the password for the first one I can login with him, but after then the login for the second not works...) :S

Could somebody check the guide, and give me some advice for changing the settings the svn server?)

*My configuration is: Apache 2.4.2 + Subversion 1.7.6.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common mistake. The htpasswd with the '-c' option creates the password file, while adding the user account. If you use the '-c' for additional accounts, it creates a new file -- wiping out the original file with the first user. Once the password file has been created, do not use the '-c' option for additional accounts. Those account will then be added to the end of the password file.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. (Sorry for the late confirm.)